# How to get default security group id with aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I want to create a serverless.yml with vpc configuration added. Assuming I don't have access to gui please tell me a method through which I can get security group id of default security group for aws services.

Comment: Have you tried `aws ec2 describe-security-groups` to list them?